# Android send picture to server

Tags: java, android, sockets, server

When I try to send a picture taken by my phone (around 2Mb) to my server I get only a really small part of the picture with awful resolution. The image is chosen from gallery. Is this because the picture is too big (resolution and size)? this is client side:

```
Intent getIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
getIntent.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(getIntent, PICK_IMAGE);

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, final Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (data == null) {
            //Display an error
            return;
        }
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {

                    server = new Socket("192.168.92.114", 4444);
                    OutputStream outputStream = server.getOutputStream();

                    in = getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData());
                    // Write to the stream:
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024]; // 1KB buffer size
                    int length = 0;
                    while ((length = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
                    }
                    outputStream.flush();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {

                    if (in != null)
                        try {
                            in.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    try {
                        server.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }
        }).start();

    }

}
```

And from the server:

```
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(ImageIO.createImageInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
frame.getContentPane().add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(img)));
```

Comment: You might consider having your server write the received image to a file, so that you can compare the original with what the server received.

Comment: This is the answer. I can't believe I didn't thought of that. Now the files are the same. Thank you!